# What files should SVN ignore when doing iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, svn

I just started using SVN for iPhone development, but there are lot of problems.  When I commit the changes, I also commit lot of unwanted files. Can anyone tell me what files I should ignore?

BTW: I am using the cornerstone subversion client .  I know I can add file extensions to ignore in preferences; but I just need to know which files I should ignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ignore these files in many projects, also .svn as I am using git:

```
.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib
build/
*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.project.xcworkspace
*.xcuserdata
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
```

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, I ignore the following items:

- the entire `build` folder
- `*.mode1v3` and `*.pbxuser` on the xcodeproj package because they are developer dependent. (That's for XCode 3.x. It could have changed with the new XCode 4, I can't say for the moment)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must ignore the **build** folder.